# Consistent unions of first-order theorems and the cardinality of the component models.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let me preface this by stating I was unsure what the title of this question should be, as any I came up with didn't fit the character limit. My apologies for it being vague.

I'm currently reading the paper "A New Correctness Proof of the Nelson-Oppen Combination Procedure", and it states the following proposition:

> **Proposition 3.1**: Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two theories. Assume that they are consistent and their respective signatures, $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, are disjoint. Then, their union is consistent iff there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ have model of cardinality $\kappa$.

I would like to understand the proof, and I understand it in the $\Leftarrow$ direction, but not in the $\Rightarrow$ direction, which states the following:

> ($\Rightarrow$) Let $T := T_1 \cup T_2$ and consider any model $M$ of $T$ (there exists at least one since $T$ is assumed to be consistent). By construction of $T$, the reduct of $M$ to $\Sigma_i$ is a model of $T_i$, for $i = 1, 2$. Obviously, both reducts have the same cardinality.

The part I do not comprehend is the last sentence, stating the reducts have the same cardinality. Why is this necessarily the case? The use of the word "obviously" makes me wonder what basic understanding I miss to really understand the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduct of $M$ to any signature uses the same underlying set, it just forgets about some interpretations. So any reduct of any structure has the same cardinality as the original structure.

If you wish to be really precise, you can do what some literature does and notationally distinguish between the structure $\mathcal{M}$ and its underlying set $M$. Now let $U(-)$ be the operation that retrieves the underlying set from a structure. So $U(\mathcal{M}) = M$ and the cardinality of $\mathcal{M}$ is $|U(\mathcal{M})| = |M|$. If we let $\mathcal{M}_i$ denote the reduct of $\mathcal{M}$ to $\Sigma_i$, then we have $U(\mathcal{M}_i) = M$, so:
$$
|U(\mathcal{M}_1)| = |M| = |U(\mathcal{M}_2)|.
$$
Often authors do not include this kind of notation because it is overly precise and may be more distracting than it does good, but maybe it helps in this case.

Comment: Aha, so the universe does not change, only the interpretation of the symbols that don't occur in $\Sigma_i$ are forgotten. I was under the assumption that the universe would also shrink, but now that I think about it that does not always make sense.